# Can I change Area, Category and Severity of error/exceptions in sharepoint 2013 log file by using diagnostics.asmx web service?

Tags: c#, logging, sharepoint-2013

I am using diagnostics.asmx web service to log error in sharepoint 2013 from .Net client side code. Errors/Exceptions get entered in the log file in 15 hive Logs folder. But the problem is I am not able to change Area, Category and Severity of error/exception in log file.
Is there any way to do so using diagnostics.asmx web service? I am using SendClientScriptErrorReport method in the web service.